# Message Box Becomes Unresponsive in Sencha Touch 2.3.1

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch

I have a Sencha Touch 2.3.1 application in which the message box does not respond sufficiently to Ext.Msg.hide() after showing and hiding the message box several times, but not at a consistent rate.

It seems to get into a state where, if I call Ext.Msg.alert('foo') and then call Ext.Msg.hide(), the message box will update with the 'foo' text and the semi-transparent mask will hide when hide() is called, but the message box won't go away and Ext.Msg.isHidden() returns true.

Here's the crazy part: I can only reproduce this by calling the same methods repeatedly and manually. I tested this by running the following endless interval in my console:

```
var j = 0;
var c = setInterval(function(){
    if(++j % 2 == 0)
        Ext.Msg.alert('Run ' + j);
    else
        Ext.Msg.hide();
}, 500)
```

As the above interval runs through hundreds of iterations, I have no issues whatsoever. The modal window opens and closes as expected. However, when I manually run `Ext.Msg.alert('foo')` and then `Ext.Msg.hide()` in the console in approximately 500ms intervals, the message box will consistently get stuck within 20 iterations.

Does anyone have the slightest clue as to how this could be debugged or what's causing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fixed. See in the sencha forum

[see fix here:](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?284450)

Comment: Still had a lot of problems with it, 'Ext.Msg.hide();' can help